# Difference in Eclipse between Gradle Dependencies and Gradle Dependencies (persisted)

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am a beginner in Gradle. What is the concept behind and the differences between `Gradle Dependencies`

[image: Gradle Dependencies]

and `Gradle Dependencies (persisted)` in Eclipse?

[image: Gradle Dependencies persisted]

How can we get from one state to another and vice versa?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Gradle` needs to know about the things that your project needs to build or run, in order to find them. We call these `incoming files`, the `dependencies` of the project. Moreover, `Gradle` needs to build and upload the things that your project produces. The `Gradle Dependencies` folder you are looking at has a list of all such dependencies(`.jar` files typically) gathered together.

**Note** that `dependencies` between `projects` and `source folder` configuration are stored in your project's metadata (the .classpath file). This means they will persist across Eclipse sessions.

Since 2.7.M2 the contents of the `classpath` container is also `persisted` in your `workspace metadata`. This reduces the time it takes for the IDE to become responsive when it starts up. However, it means you may need to manually trigger a refresh once in a while. You can tell whether a container was initialized from `persisted` state because it will be labelled as it's name is, under the `Gradle Dependencies (persisted)`.

That's the only difference. One is `Persisted`, the other is not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 nice answer thanks. I still have a few questions, what does 2.7.M2 mean? What kind of refresh you mean in "refresh once in a while", project refresh, gradle refresh and what "once a while" mean exactly?

Comment: 2.7.M2 - Maven version 2.7 onwards,
Refresh as in, right click on your project and select refresh. It just re-Builds the path in a shorter manner. 
Once in a while as in, whenever you make some changes. Maven heavily chaches everything within eclipse itself. To allow the new version to be used and not the cached version, you need to refresh once in a while i.e. when you think your changes arent working the way they should. For Maven related changes you should follow up to updating your maven project. Easily possible by `Alt+F5` or RightClick on project->Maven->Update Project.
Hope this helps.